# Pageable and @Param in a spring data JpaRepository method issue [2]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170972/pageable-and-param-in-a-spring-data-jparepository-method-issue) question, but using `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.7.0.RELEASE` I'm still having the same issue (`Either use @Param on all parameters except Pageable and Sort typed once, or none at all!`). My class is:

```
public interface BalanceHistoryRepository extends JpaRepository<BalanceHistory, Long> {
    @Query("select bh from BalanceHistory bh where bh.account.id = :idAccount")
    public BalanceHistory findCurrentBalanceByAccountNumber(PageRequest pageCriteira, @Param("idAccount") long idAccount);
}
```

**Edit**

Call:

```
 Pageable page = new PageRequest(0, 1, Sort.Direction.DESC, "date");
        BalanceHistory bh = balanceHistoryRepository.findCurrentBalanceByAccountNumber(1,page);
```

Method:

```
@Query("select bh from BalanceHistory bh where bh.account.id = :idAccount")
public BalanceHistory findCurrentBalanceByAccountNumber(@Param("idAccount") long idAccount, Pageable pageCriteira);
```

Comment: The bug is in spring-data-commons if you have a dependency on an older version of spring-data-commons upgrading spring-data-jpa won't help.

Comment: Those java.lang guys need to chill out....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Make sure you use `Pageable` instead of `PageRequest` so that the first parameter is recognized as one not to be bound to the actual query. Also, you need to change the return type to either `Page` or `List` as you'll return multiple results mostly.

```
public interface BalanceHistoryRepository extends CrudRepository<BalanceHistory, Long> {

  @Query("select bh from BalanceHistory bh where bh.account.id = :idAccount")
  Page<BalanceHistory> findCurrentBalanceByAccountNumber(@Param("idAccount") long idAccount, Pageable pageable);
}
```

This should do the trick. Note, that we generally recommend *not* to extend the store specific interfaces as they expose store-specific API that should only be exposed if really necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the input! This change yields a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has to have one of the following return types! [interface org.springframework.data.domain.Slice, interface org.springframework.data.domain.Page, interface java.util.List]` exception. See my edit please :)

Comment: Fix your return type. You put in a `Pageable` so the result has to be a page of results not a single result.

Comment: @Oliver: Why does the parameter have to be `Pageable` and i i mage the param a `PageRequest` it throws this exception mentioned in the question.

Comment: Because you refer to interfaces, not implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same exception when I accidentally imported the wrong `Pageable` class.

This can also happen if you use `PageRequest` in the repository as well.

it should be,

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following query

```
  @Query("SELECT c FROM yourTable c where c.isActive=?1 and c.isDelete='N' ORDER BY c.companyAccId DESC")
        Page<yourTable > findAllByIsActiveAndIsDelete( String isActive,Pageable pageable);
```