# Spring boot: How to configure pagination on a @RepositoryRestResource?

Tags: pagination, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I've looked at both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170972/pageable-and-param-in-a-spring-data-jparepository-method-issue) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975159/pageable-and-param-in-a-spring-data-jparepository-method-issue-2). But I have still not been able to setup paging for a repository method. Not sure if I'm affected by a bug or simply not writing this correctly. Basically I'm asking if someone could provide an example of how to implement paging on a repository method which gets exported through the @RepositoryRestResource annotation?

My attempt at achieving pagination

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Page<User> findByUserGroup(@Param("userGroup") String userGroup,
                                            @Param("page") Pageable pageable);

}
```

The error message generated by the code

```
Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.project.repository.UserRepository.findByUserGroup(java.lang.String,java.awt.print.Pageable)
```

I've also tried removing the method param for pageable which then resulted in this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either use @Param on all parameters except Pageable and Sort typed once, or none at all!
```

Dependencies I'm using in this project.

1. Oracle java 8.
2. "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE",
3. "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
4. "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator",
5. 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail',
6. "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf",
7. "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security",
8. "org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.0.RC2",
9. "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa",
10. "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest",

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update: The final solution**

Adding this as reference for anyone else wondering how to do this. The main difference was that I had to make sure to import the right `Pageable`  object as noted in the chosen answer.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Page<User> findByUserGroup(@Param("userGroup") String userGroup, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using the Pageable class from the wrong package: `java.awt.print.Pageable`. You should be using `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable`

Comment: Well spotted! That was exactly the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems little late but their is easier solution for pagination.  See below code snippet.

```
public interface NotebookRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Notebook, Long> {
```

For complete example please go through this [blog](http://sv-technical.blogspot.com/2015/11/spring-boot-and-repositoryrestresource.html)

Comment: I can see people going to my blog, if this solution works please up vote.